# TFS 2018 Transition Field Updates Not Working Properly

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, workitem

1. I created two custom states in my TFS flow. (For Feedback and Assigned).
2. I created two custom fields that will hold the date once it is transitioned to the state (Feedback Date and Assigned Date)
3. During transition to a phase, I have set the value of the current serverclock to the mapped field.

```html
<FIELD name="Assigned Date" refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.AssignedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
<FIELD name="Feedback Date" refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.FeedbackDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />

<STATE value="Assigned">
</STATE>

<STATE value="For Feedback">
</STATE>

 <TRANSITION from="For Feedback" to="Assigned">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Assigned" />
  </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.AssignedDate">
      <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
     </FIELD>
  </FIELDS> 
 </TRANSITION>
 
  <TRANSITION from="Assigned" to="For Feedback">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="For Feedback" />
  </REASONS>
 <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.FeedbackDate">
      <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
     </FIELD>
  </FIELDS> 
 </TRANSITION>
```

Both dates (Assigned and Feedback date are updated for both transitions). Can someone push me to the right direction why it behaves this way and how to work around it.

Currently using TFS 2018 On Prem

Answer (score 1):

You use the same **CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.AssignedDate** field in both transitions.

Comment: Was a typo error. Had some company information on the field name so had to adjust. Actual wit did not have that mistake. Fixed question

Answer (score 0):

I've tested in Tfs2018.Update3.2 with the definition below and it works as expected. When transit from `Assigned` to `For Feedback`, field `Feedback Date` update to current time. When transit from `For Feedback` to `Assigned`, field `Assigned Date` update to current time.

```
<FieldDefinition name="Assigned Date" refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.AssignedDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />
<FieldDefinition name="Feedback Date" refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.FeedbackDate" type="DateTime" reportable="dimension" />

<State value="Assigned" />
<State value="For Feedback" />

<Transition from="Assigned" to="For Feedback">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="For Feedback" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.FeedbackDate">
      <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</Transition>
<Transition from="For Feedback" to="Assigned">
  <REASONS>
    <DEFAULTREASON value="Assigned" />
  </REASONS>
  <FIELDS>
    <FIELD refname="CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.AssignedDate">
      <SERVERDEFAULT from="clock" />
    </FIELD>
  </FIELDS>
</Transition>
```

Comment: My version is TFS 2018 Update 2. Do you think an update will fix it?

Comment: @TheProvost No, update will not fix this problem.The problem is in logic, maybe there is another place that updates your fields.

Comment: @Cece Dong - MSFT mine updates as well but both dates are updated. Did check if   not both of them were updated?

Comment: @ShamraiAleksander By another place what do you mean? This is a newly created field and all updates are in the xml file. A quick search all for the field name will tell me if its use in any other parts for the wit.

Answer (score 0):

That`s really interesting situation but we can not see the full content of your work item type definition. However, you can test the workaround:

1. Add new rule WHENNOT for your field (for example CustomFields.Groundup.Workitem.FeedbackDate).
2. The rule something like that:

   ```
   <WHENNOT field="System.State" value="For Feedback">
       <READONLY/> //or frozen
   </WHENNOT>
   ```